# OCCI error: ORA-01480: trailing null missing from STR bind value

Tags: c++, oracle, occi

I try to insert data into a table with OCCI C++.

I got some examples and tried to report them in my program without success.

My problem is that I have std::string(s) in my data model and I need to convert them into 2D char arrays to be used by the setDataBuffer method.

I cannot find where is the wrong code because I first allocate the rows of the 2D arrays and for each row I allocate the size of the string + 1 (for the null char) and the function std::strcpy normally adds the null char to the destination.

I cannot understand why Oracle says that I give a buffer without null char !

Here is my code, everything works fine until the line:

**statement->executeArrayUpdate(numberOfLinks)**

```
// Open a database connection
oracle::occi::Connection* connection = LBCDatabase::instance().getConnection();

// Structures to store results
int numberOfLinks = model.numberOfLinksOfType(linkType) / 2;

char** simulationIdBuffer = new char*[numberOfLinks];
char** linkIdBuffer = new char*[numberOfLinks];
char** linkTypeBuffer = new char*[numberOfLinks];

unsigned short* simulationIdBufferLength = new unsigned short[numberOfLinks];
unsigned short* linkIdBufferLength = new unsigned short[numberOfLinks];
unsigned short* linkTypeBufferLength = new unsigned short[numberOfLinks];

// Simulation id is common for all links
std::string simulationId = model.simulationId();

// Loop on FWD links
int linkIndex{ 0 };
for (const std::shared_ptr<Link>& link : model.links())
{
    // Skip RTN links and FWD links UP
    if (ELinkType::RTN == link->linkType() ||
        (ELinkType::FWD == link->linkType() && ELinkSide::UP == link->linkSide()))
        continue;

    // Get datas for current link
    std::string linkId = LBCUtils::restoreLinkId(link->linkId());
    std::string linkType = LBCUtils::enumToString<ELinkType>(link->linkType());

    // Add them into buffers
    simulationIdBuffer[linkIndex] = new char[simulationId.length() + 1];
    std::strcpy(simulationIdBuffer[linkIndex], simulationId.c_str());

    linkIdBuffer[linkIndex] = new char[linkId.length() + 1];
    std::strcpy(linkIdBuffer[linkIndex], linkId.c_str());

    linkTypeBuffer[linkIndex] = new char[linkType.length() + 1];
    std::strcpy(linkTypeBuffer[linkIndex], linkType.c_str());

    // Store the length
    simulationIdBufferLength[linkIndex] = simulationId.length() + 1;
    linkIdBufferLength[linkIndex] = linkId.length() + 1;
    linkTypeBufferLength[linkIndex] = linkType.length() + 1;

    ++linkIndex;
}

// Create the query
std::string query("INSERT INTO res_link ");
query.append("(simulation_id, link_id, link_type) ");
query.append("VALUES(:1, :2, :3)");

oracle::occi::Statement* statement = connection->createStatement(query);
statement->setDataBuffer(1, (dvoid*)simulationIdBuffer, oracle::occi::OCCI_SQLT_STR, sizeof(simulationIdBuffer[0]), simulationIdBufferLength);
statement->setDataBuffer(2, (dvoid*)linkIdBuffer, oracle::occi::OCCI_SQLT_STR, sizeof(linkIdBuffer[0]), linkIdBufferLength);
statement->setDataBuffer(3, (dvoid*)linkTypeBuffer, oracle::occi::OCCI_SQLT_STR, sizeof(linkTypeBuffer[0]), linkTypeBufferLength);

// Execute the query
statement->executeArrayUpdate(numberOfLinks);   // Exception here: ORA-01480: trailing null missing from STR bind value
connection->commit();

// Cleanup buffers
delete[] simulationIdBufferLength;
delete[] linkIdBufferLength;
delete[] linkTypeBufferLength;
LBCUtils::deleteCharBuffer(simulationIdBuffer, numberOfLinks);
LBCUtils::deleteCharBuffer(linkIdBuffer, numberOfLinks);
LBCUtils::deleteCharBuffer(linkTypeBuffer, numberOfLinks);

// Cleanup before to go out
connection->terminateStatement(statement);
LBCDatabase::instance().releaseConnection(connection);
```

When I log the content of my arrays the output is correct.

Thanks a lot if somebody can help me...
Regards.

Comment: `statement->setDataBuffer(1, (dvoid*)simulationIdBuffer, oracle::occi::OCCI_SQLT_STR, sizeof(simulationIdBuffer[0]), simulationIdBufferLength);` -- I have never used OCCI, but are you sure that `sizeof(simulationBuffer[0])` is what you want to do?  That does *not* give you the number of characters allocated.  That simply gives you the `sizeof(char *)`, which will be either 4 or 8, depending on the bitness of the program.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This code comes from the official occi documentation. It seems to me that this parameters works with the next parameter which contains the length of each string. But maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: The `sizeof` will only work for an actual character array, not one dynamically allocated from a pointer.